# Keras & Theano, Python 3.5, Windows 10 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, theano, keras

I am trying to use Keras with a Theano backend to work, so far I have just tried to import Kera like so.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

And I get a huge output error which I'm not too sure how to fix.

```
Using Theano backend.
===============================
00001   #include <Python.h>
00002   #include "theano_mod_helper.h"
.....   ............
01081   PyMODINIT_FUNC
01082   PyInit_lazylinker_ext(void) {
01083   #else
01084   #define RETVAL
01085   PyMODINIT_FUNC
01086   initlazylinker_ext(void) 
01087   {
01088   #endif
01089       PyObject* m;
01090   
01091       lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType.tp_new = PyType_GenericNew;
01092       if (PyType_Ready(&lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType) < 0)
01093           return RETVAL;
01094   #if defined(NPY_PY3K)
01095       m = PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
01096   #else
01097       m = Py_InitModule3("lazylinker_ext", lazylinker_ext_methods,
01098                          "Example module that creates an extension type.");
01099   #endif
01100       Py_INCREF(&lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType);
01101       PyModule_AddObject(m, "CLazyLinker", (PyObject *)&lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType);
01102   
01103       return RETVAL;
01104   }
01105   
===============================
In file included from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/Python.h:50:0,
Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
                 from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/pyport.h:686:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
 #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
  ^
In file included from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/Python.h:133:0,
"C:\cygwin64\bin\g++.exe" -shared -g -march=broadwell -mmmx -mno-3dnow -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -mno-sse4a -mcx16 -msahf -mmovbe -maes -mno-sha -mpclmul -mpopcnt -mabm -mno-lwp -mfma -mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mbmi -mbmi2 -mno-tbm -mavx -mavx2 -msse4.2 -msse4.1 -mlzcnt -mrtm -mhle -mrdrnd -mf16c -mfsgsbase -mrdseed -mprfchw -madx -mfxsr -mxsave -mxsaveopt -mno-avx512f -mno-avx512er -mno-avx512cd -mno-avx512pf -mno-prefetchwt1 -mclflushopt -mxsavec -mxsaves -mno-avx512dq -mno-avx512bw -mno-avx512vl -mno-avx512ifma -mno-avx512vbmi -mno-clwb -mno-pcommit -mno-mwaitx --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=6144 -mtune=generic -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -DMS_WIN64 -I"C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include" -I"C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof" -L"C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\libs" -L"C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3" -o C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp -lpython36
                 from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:23:5: error: '__int64' does not name a type
     __int64 st_ino;
     ^
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:29:5: error: '__int64' does not name a type
     __int64 st_size;
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/sys/stat.h:22:0,
                 from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/pyport.h:227,
                 from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/Python.h:50,
                 from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:30:12: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
     time_t st_atime;
            ^
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:30:12: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
     time_t st_atime;
            ^
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:32:12: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
     time_t st_mtime;
            ^
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:32:12: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
     time_t st_mtime;
            ^
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:34:12: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
     time_t st_ctime;
            ^
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:34:12: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
     time_t st_ctime;
            ^
In file included from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/Python.h:8:0,
                 from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/pyconfig.h:269:23: error: '__int64' does not name a type
 # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64
                       ^
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:309:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'
 typedef PY_LONG_LONG npy_longlong;
         ^
In file included from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:22:0,
                 from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7:
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:310:31: error: expected initializer before 'npy_ulonglong'
 typedef unsigned PY_LONG_LONG npy_ulonglong;
                               ^
In file included from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:22:0,
                 from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7:
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:611:17: error: 'npy_longlong' does not name a type
         typedef npy_longlong npy_int64;
                 ^
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:612:17: error: 'npy_ulonglong' does not name a type
         typedef npy_ulonglong npy_uint64;
                 ^
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:1090:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type
 typedef npy_int64 npy_timedelta;
         ^
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:1091:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type
 typedef npy_int64 npy_datetime;
         ^
In file included from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18:0,
                 from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:23,
                 from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7:
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:742:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type
         npy_int64 year;
         ^
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:748:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type
         npy_int64 day;
         ^
In file included from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7:0:
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h: In function 'int npy_PyFile_DupClose2(PyObject*, FILE*, off_t)':
C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:274:41: error: 'lseek' was not declared in this scope
     if (npy_lseek(fd, orig_pos, SEEK_SET) == -1) {
                                         ^

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 75, in <module>
    raise ImportError()
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 92, in <module>
    raise ImportError()
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Def/Dropbox/Dissertation/deepLearning.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from .theano_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 3, in <module>
    import theano
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from theano.compile import (
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function_module import *
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 21, in <module>
    import theano.compile.mode
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 10, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 662, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 127, in <module>
    preargs=args)
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2316, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): In file included from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/Python.h:50:0,.                  from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/pyport.h:686:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?).".  #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?).".   ^. In file included from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/Python.h:133:0,.                  from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:23:5: error: '__int64' does not name a type.      __int64 st_ino;.      ^. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:29:5: error: '__int64' does not name a type.      __int64 st_size;.      ^. In file included from /usr/include/sys/stat.h:22:0,.                  from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/pyport.h:227,.                  from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/Python.h:50,.                  from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:30:12: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration.      time_t st_atime;.             ^. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:30:12: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token.      time_t st_atime;.             ^. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:32:12: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration.      time_t st_mtime;.             ^. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:32:12: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token.      time_t st_mtime;.             ^. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:34:12: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration.      time_t st_ctime;.             ^. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/fileutils.h:34:12: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token.      time_t st_ctime;.             ^. In file included from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/Python.h:8:0,.                  from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\include/pyconfig.h:269:23: error: '__int64' does not name a type.  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64.                        ^. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:309:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'.  typedef PY_LONG_LONG npy_longlong;.          ^. In file included from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:22:0,.                  from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7:. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:310:31: error: expected initializer before 'npy_ulonglong'.  typedef unsigned PY_LONG_LONG npy_ulonglong;.                                ^. In file included from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:22:0,.                  from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7:. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:611:17: error: 'npy_longlong' does not name a type.          typedef npy_longlong npy_int64;.                  ^. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:612:17: error: 'npy_ulonglong' does not name a type.          typedef npy_ulonglong npy_uint64;.                  ^. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:1090:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type.  typedef npy_int64 npy_timedelta;.          ^. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:1091:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type.  typedef npy_int64 npy_datetime;.          ^. In file included from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18:0,.                  from C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:23,.                  from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7:. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:742:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type.          npy_int64 year;.          ^. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:748:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type.          npy_int64 day;.          ^. In file included from C:\Users\Def\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.6.0-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7:0:. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h: In function 'int npy_PyFile_DupClose2(PyObject*, FILE*, off_t)':. C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:274:41: error: 'lseek' was not declared in this scope.      if (npy_lseek(fd, orig_pos, SEEK_SET) == -1) {.                                          ^. 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Now to me this looks like it has a compilation issue with some Cython code and it not being able to compile properly but what should I do to fix this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So after some deeper looking I found that my Windows 10 system had a bunch of C++ compiler that was conflicting which the library, not just MinGW.

Also, CygWin which was also causing a problem after I deleted these compilers and took their location our of my Path it worked.

So I recommend if you struggle with the same problem do a scan for any 'g++' compilers you might have forgotten about in your system and check your Paths!